# How to find and print the trend point change

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

My logic I am working on:

I'm trying to print out the results for the change points.

Trend change points are those points where the array changes its direction and goes from increasing to decreasing order or decreasing to increasing order.

I should be getting: 11 8 5 10 but I'm only getting parts of it. **Is my approach the correct way to do this?*

```
numberss = [1,4,9,11,8,3,2,5,10]
trendpoints(numberss,len(numberss))

def trendpoints(number_array, length):
    print("length", length)
    print(number_array)
    # -1 on the array because we dont need to jump to the last number (fake fix)
    for num in range(1, length-1):
        # check last, current and next
        # if current greater then current and less then next
        # [1,4,9,11,8,3,2,5,10]
        # 11 hit 8 CHANGE UP print both
        if num <= length:
            #print(number_array[num-1])
            #print(number_array[num])
            #print(number_array[num+1])

            # 9 11 8
            # 11 > 9
            # 11 < 8

            # 2 5 10
            # 2 < 5
            # 10 > 5
            if ((number_array[num] > number_array[num-1] and number_array[num] > number_array[num+1])
                or (number_array[num] < number_array[num-1] and number_array[num] > number_array[num+1])):
                #print("CHANGE")
                print(number_array[num])
                #print(number_array[num+1])
            print("---")
```

My result:

```
length 9
[1, 4, 9, 11, 8, 3, 2, 5, 10]
---
---
11
---
8
---
3
---
---
---
```

Comment: why are 8 and 10 included in your expected outcome? The only 2 times it changes from increasing to decreasing(and opposite) is 11  and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, 11 and 2 are the only expected solutions. Here is a short solution using list comprehensions: (assumes no repeat numbers)

```
def trendpoints(number_array, length):
    diff_array = [number_array[i] - number_array[i - 1] for i in range(1, length)]
    trend_array = [number_array[i] for i in range(1, length - 1) if diff_array[i] * diff_array[i - 1] <= 0]
    return trend_array
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually kind of a calculus problem. In calculus, a local min or max is defined when the input to the derivative of the parent function in either direction produces an output which has opposite signs (all extrema are defined when the derivative is equal to zero, but that also includes points which aren't necessarily local min/max).

In this case you can just subtract the values on either side from your current value and if they have opposite signs, it's a min or a max.

```
for i, v in enumerate(numberss):
    ldiff = 0
    if i > 0:
        ldiff = v-numerberss[i-1]
    rdiff = 0
    if i < len(numberss)-1:
        rdiff = numberss[i+1]-v
     # if they're opposite signs, ldiff*rdiff is < 0
    is_extrema = ldiff*rdiff < 0
```

fendall's answer provides a more pythonic way of expressing this using list comprehensions.